# using maven pom while creating jar:test-jar some times it says JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion

Tags: java, maven, jar

While creating jar with test classes by `jar:test-jar` sometimes it says:

> JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!

Test-jar doesn't contain any test classes. But sometimes correct test jar is created with all test classes.

**what i need to mention in my pom to get test module jar without test classes run(only compile)**

what maven command needed with respect to maven pom

Comment: actually, there is no question in this question

Comment: Are you really calling `jar:test-jar` manually ?

Comment: yes.from eclipse runconfig-->in goal field i entered jar:test-jar and then runned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests

Add this in your pom.xml

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if there is no compiled classes in your output directory. See [testClassesDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html#testClassesDirectory).

For example, if you run `mvn install` (which also triggers `compile` phase) and then `mvn jar:test-jar` you will get jar with test classes. But if you run `mvn clean` and then `mvn jar:test-jar` you will get message about empty jar and therefore generated jar will be empty.

Comment: thank you.but even my pom install also some times gives all main classes jar and some times not .Can you provide me the sample pom that generates jar as you said(test and main classes with dependencies)

Comment: @user3863263 I don't think that's a good idea. May be you could share you pom.xml. Also, always consider creating new project via archetype to be sure that project structure is correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977602/facing-issue-in-java-project-with-maven-jar-includes-test-and-main-modulescrea  is link in which my pom present .