# Can't find main class in Maven generated project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, acceleo, mainclass

I'm using Acceleo to create a maven project which creates a .jar app... I have a "generate.mtl" file, calling other .mtl files one of which is the following genPOM.mtl

```
[comment encoding = UTF-8 /]
[module genPOM('file:/C:/Users/xxx/workspace/PSMToText/model/PSMMetamodel.ecore')]


[template public genPOM(aService : Service)]

[file (aService.name + '/pom.xml', false, 'UTF-8')]
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>"some-group-id"</groupId>
 <artifactId>[aService.name/]</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>[aService.name/]</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    [if (aServicePSM.serviceDatabaseType = 'MySQL')]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    [else]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    [/if]
 </dependencies>
 <build>
    <finalName>[aService.name/]</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>[aService.name/]ServiceTester.[aService.name/]ServiceTester</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
</project>

[/file]
[/template]
```

I have the Acceleo code producing a number of .java files of which the main function exists in the following file named WSATServiceTester.java:

```
package WSATServiceTester;

public class WSATServiceTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testService();
    }

    public static void testService(){
//blah blah code...
    }
};
```

So... my Acceleo code produces some java files in ".../PSMToText/output" directory and a pom.xml file in ".../PSMToText/output/WSAT" directory... and nothing else..

Now.. when i'm browsing the ".../output/WSAT" directory and write "mvn package" i get the following "BUILD SUCCESS" message
[image]

and a "target" folder is created in the ".../output/WSAT" directory containing a WSAT.jar file and a "maven-archiver" folder containing a "pom.properties" file which is the following

```
#Generated by Maven
#Wed Jun 28 18:07:10 EEST 2017
version=1.0-SNAPSHOT
groupId="some-group-id"
artifactId=WSAT
```

But... when I try to execute the .jar file writing "java -jar WSAT.jar" I get this message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   WSATServiceTester.WSATServiceTester

So.. I googled a lot and searched in here and read about a MANIFEST.MF file which should contain configurations about where to find the main class but I don't get that generated somehow... also the "pom.properties" file contains nothing about that matter either.

I'm in a general confuse with all that acceleo-maven-java-pom.xml-MANIFEST.MF stuff so any help would be... helpful... :)

If I made that too confusing I'm willing to answer any questions of yours...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is the `WSATServiceTester` class located inside the jar file?

Comment: I don't know... how do i find that out??

Comment: Open the jar file using a program like winrar or 7zip.

Comment: Actually.. there are no .java files in it... :/

Comment: Somewhere in the screenshot I posted says "[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!" could this be relevant???

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956226/5200287) answer may be able to help.

Comment: nah not helpful.. same thing happens.. no java files in my .jar... maybe this has to do something with it:
"Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\bill\workspace\PSMToText\output\WSAT\src\test\resources"
I have no src/test/resource folder anywhere.... so what is this??

Comment: Sorry, that's as far as my knowledge goes on Maven, although you can just manually create a working jar file if this is urgent.

Comment: This looks more like you need help with maven than with Acceleo. I'd suggest posting the (generated) pom.xml filr here so that people can help you given the final look of that file.